# ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'employee' in 'field list' in MySQL

Tags: mysql

## I'm not sure why I'm getting this error message ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'employee' in 'field list'.

[Employee Table Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJX9i.png)

[Employee Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJm1R.png)

[Work Table Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPQ6Q.png)

[Work Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdcMn.png)

This is the datatypes for Employee Table and the values inserted:

```
mysql> create table employee (`employee-name` char(30), `street` char(30), 
`city` char(30));
mysql> insert into employee values ('John Smith', 'Street A', 'City 1');
mysql> insert into employee values ('Arya Stark', 'Street B', 'City 2');
mysql> insert into employee values ('Barry Allen', 'Street C', 'City 3');
mysql> insert into employee values ('Wanda Maximoff', 'Street D', 'City 4');
mysql> insert into employee values ('Raven Roth', 'Street E', 'City 5');
```

This is the datatypes for Work Table and values inserted:

```
mysql> create table works (`employee-name` char(30), `company-name` char(50), 
`salary` decimal(20,2));
mysql> insert into works values ('John Smith', 'MyBank', '10000');
mysql> insert into works values ('Arya Stark', 'First Bank Corporation', 
'20000');
mysql> insert into works values ('Barry Allen', 'MyBank', '17000');
mysql> insert into works values ('Wanda Maximoff', 'YourBank', '125000');
mysql> insert into works values ('Raven Roth', 'MyBank', '20000');
```

**The question I got from my lab practical is:** Find the names, street address,
and cities of residence for all employees who work for 'First Bank
Corporation' and earn more than $10,000

Every time I enter this the error comes up:

```
select employee.employee-name, employee.street, employee.city from
employee, works
where employee.employee-name=works.employee-name
and company-name = 'First Bank Corporation' and salary > 10000;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'employee.employee' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Subtracting name from employee seems like an odd thing to do

Comment: avoid using special charcters instead use camel case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape table/column names containing special characters like `-`

```
select employee.`employee-name`...
```

Besides don't use the legacy join style any more. It was replaced by explicit joins 20 years ago.

```
select e.`employee-name`, e.street, e.city
from employee e
join works w on e.`employee-name` = w.`employee-name`
where `company-name` = 'First Bank Corporation' 
and salary > 10000
```

Comment: I would go further. Including '-' within table / column identifiers is a disaster waiting to happen.